# Viewing peak concurrent RDP connections

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I have a requirement to view the peak concurrent RDP connections on a Windows Server 2012R2 server.

The license limit is 35, but I need to know how close we have come to reaching this number.

Is there a way to view this data or to start logging this now?

Basically we need to know how close we have come to using the 35 licenses at any one time (concurrent connections).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Remote Desktop Licensing is not based on concurrent connections. If Microsoft were to audit you, it would measure the number of licenses you have installed (for per-computer licensing), or the msTSExpireDate attribute on user accounts (for per-user licensing). You need a license for any user account that has logged on to a remote desktop session host server within the last 90 days. Per-computer licensing doesn't really need to be measured because it is enforced.

Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1640.microsoft-assessment-and-planning-toolkit.aspx

Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit Reports
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17804.how-to-use-the-map-toolkit.aspx#Phase_6_Review_the_Reports

Comment: Hello Greg, thank you for the clarification on this, much appreciated. Just to ensure I have understood, this is measured on the number of accounts created and whether they are active and have logged in within the last 90 days? That would be considered an active user, correct? So if we have an RDS licensing of 35, there can only be 35 users that can log in within a 90 day period? Or there can only be 35 user accounts created (assuming they all log in frequently (within 90 days)?

Answer (score 0):

But it would be interesting to be able to view this to get a idea on how many users are concurrently using the MS RDS server, to get an idea of the load and based upon that to be able to determine whether to scale horizontally or vertically.
Is there any way to see how many users are concurrently using the MS RDS server ?
Please advise.